# How to get canvas area click?

Tags: android, view, charts, pie-chart

I have drawn piechart using canvas method of view , but now i want get click of individual pie ? how can i dot that?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got perfect answer for this question:

get color code of click area and check if color match with your color code this will get click you want.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    float touchX = event.getX();

    float touchY = event.getY();

    Logger.debug("X-->"+touchX+" Y---->"+touchY);

    //get drawing cache of your view
    Bitmap bitmap = getDrawingCache(true);

            //Get color code of pixle where you have tap
    int colorCode=bitmap.getPixel((int)touchX,(int)touchY);

    if(colorCode == context.getResources().getColor(R.color.pie_blue)) {
        Logger.debug("Color blue");
        onPieClick.onBluePieClick(touchX,touchY);
    }else if(colorCode == context.getResources().getColor(R.color.pie_green)) {
        Logger.debug("Color green");
        onPieClick.onGreenPieClick(touchX,touchY);
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is,

- Override onTouch event & You will get Motion event,
- You will get x & y co-ordinates of the click by event.getX() &
         event.getY() respectively.
- identify where this x & y intersect in pie.

Sample code:

1)Simple

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        float xCord=event.getX();
        float yCord = event.getY();
        ....
        Write condition to identify where this x & y intersect in pie.
        ...
    }
    return true;
}
```

2) Another way getting touch (good way)

```
OnGestureListener mGestureListener=new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            float xCord=e.getX();
            float yCord = e.getY();
            ....
            identify where this x & y intersect in pie.
            ...
        };
    };
GestureDetector gestureDetector=new GestureDetector(context, mGestureListener);
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Well, at least not directly.

You could do the following though:

1. In the click handler for the view, determine the xy coordinates of the click
2. Compare the drawing code you wrote, thereby determining in which piece of the pie the click was